# single quotes versus double quotes in js

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to Use Double or Single Quotes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript)

Are there any differences between single and double quotes in javascript?

Comment: Hey, @homey1, I think you need to accept an answer :) ( This question / post is getting quite old, still without a green tick :)

Answer (score 7):

No, is the right answer most of the time. However if you want to write valid JSON, then you should use double quotes for object literals.

Answer (score 5):

No, **except** in double quotes you can put single quotes.

e.g. "Don't not do this"

And in single quotes you can put double quotes.

e.g. 'John said "Do this"'

Comment: **except** that both your sentences say the same thing. *Don't not do this* is a double negative :)

Comment: In javascript, php, c, etc, you can escape the innerquotes with a backslash \"

Answer (score 3):

One is slightly wider, so you may have a few extra characters disappear to the right (as opposed to the slimmer version) in your favourite IDE.

Seriously though, I always use ', because if I need to quote a HTML element attribute, I always use " and I can't be bothered escaping like so

```
var html = "<a href=\"http://www.example.com\">hello</a>"
```

Comment: +1 to offset the -1. I laughed (well, on the inside anyway).

Comment: yeah, i'd upvote it too, but you must be severely punished by suggesting (even as a joke) to use proportional fonts for programming.  (it's sometimes forgivable for comments, _never_ for code)

Comment: Haha, :) Fixed width font is the only way to go!

Comment: @Javier: Do you realize that you can be more productive using variable width because there is less scrolling **:)** (+1 for variable width)

Answer (score 3):

No difference. Just make sure you close the string with whatever you open it with.

Much more sensible to me than other languages (looking at you, C# and PHP...) where single quoted strings are either character literals, or don't expand escaped characters.

Answer (score 2):

You would mostly use " unless in a position in where you can't escape it. ( It is neater to most developers, Don't ask why )
Also `"$myVar"` in php will allow the string to have the variables value. ( I know its not javascript, but another example..
In bash,

```
   echo "What is your name?\nMy name is $(whoami)."
```

will run the function / command whoami.

```
<button onclick="dosomething(\"test\")">Test</button> Won't work 
<button onclick="dosomething("test")">Test</button> Won't work 
<section id='"Where-As">
    <button onclick="dosomething('test')">Test</button>
    <!-- will work -->
</section>
```

P.S: Valid JSON objects should be using double quotes.

#### Other fun with different quotes:

```
console.log('\n\n\n\n');  // Will give you \n\n\n\n as a string.
console.log("\n\n\n\n"); // Will give lines.
```

Comment: However, if you **are** ***obsessed*** with double quotes, you can use `onclick="dosomething(&quot;test&quot;)"`

Comment: Seriously though, ***why*** should someone "always" use double quotes? (for normal circumstances / ignoring my joke)

Comment: @george: No one needs double quotes, just usually prefure " over ' as it looks nicer to lots of people. ( No change in the binary length, so worthless requirement :)