# Google Maps API geocoding

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding, innertext

I'm using Google Maps API geocoding to turn an address into a location on the map. I have it set up as:

var address = document.getElementById("address").innerText;

I have my address div set up as

123 candycane lane (br />
north pole, antartica

Whenver I put a 
 after the first line, the geocoding won't return any results. But when I remove it and have the address as one line, the geocoder works perfectly. I had thought innerText did not account for HTML such as (br />. Is there anyway to make it so it skips over the line break?

Thanks

P.S. I know my line breaks have parantheses at the beginning, but its because my post wasnt recognizing the HTML line break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.innerText does not return a linebreak-tag (br), as you say, but it returns a newline character (\n).

Simple solution (replace it with a blank space):

```
var address = document.getElementById('address').innerText.replace(/\n/g, ' ');
```

Edit,
.replace() is a method on the string object, which takes a regular expression as a first parameter. The 'g' stands for *global*, which means it should replace all occurrences of \n. Without it, only the first occurrence would be replaced. The second parameter is the substitute string.

Comment: I understand that \n is the newline character, but can you explain what (/\n/g, ' '), the whole thing means? I'm new to javascript so I'm unsure of what it does.

Thanks

Comment: This is a regular expression search and replace. \n means newline, the pattern goes betweeen slashes /like this/, g is a global modifier meaning 'replace every newline with the replacement text', and the last parameter, ' ', is the replacement text.

Comment: also, when doing something like 'address', can you use "address" or is 'address' best?

Comment: @sukh: In this case it doesn't matter, but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript