# Difference between " and ' characters in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to Use Double or Single Quotes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript)

I think `$('#id')` and `$("#id")` both is valid so `"` and `'` character is samething and it is just preference to use `'` instead of `"` ?

Comment: not related to JQuery but js in general , they are both strings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Single- and double-quotes do the same thing in JavaScript: they delimit string constants. It's convenient (though a little weird) to have both types of quotes available for the same purpose, because it makes quoting strings with embedded quotes a little easier sometimes. One example: jQuery selectors:

```
$('input[name="my input"]').val('');
```

Comment: Now it is clearer in my mind.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is just a JavaScript library.

A string quoted with `'` characters have have `"` characters inside it without them being escaped — and vice versa — that is all.

Comment: Right, JQuery is just framework of javascript but it always looks like have different syntax with $ character.

Comment: Sadly, stupid variable names do not stop JavaScript being JavaScript.

Comment: @Freshblood: `$` is just an identifier like `x` or `hasNinjas`.

Comment: @David - why stupid? they make your life easier?

Comment: @ifaour: It's just a matter of opinion. The ECMA standard says that the $ character is valid but recommends it to be reserved for machine generated code - like code generated by GWT or a macro processor or, if they exist, self-aware robots. So some purists consider them stupid since they don't consider regular programmers to be robots. I for one know some people in HR, marketing and accounting who think programmers are closely related to robots.

Comment: Stupid because it is a meaningless symbol. Variables should be meaningful. `$` says nothing about its purpose, and even if you know it is a magic function name, it doesn't tell you if it is jQuery's `$` or MooTool's `$` or Prototype.js's `$` or another `$` entirely.

Answer (score 0):

`'` and `"` may be used interchangeably in JavaScript/jQuery.

It's a little more robust to use `'`.

Why? Because it's easier to move JavaScript code between `script` tags and inline HTML elements - common XHTML syntax is to wrap event code in `""` (eg `onclick="alert('foo')"`).  Using single quotes prevents the need to escape (eg `"alert(\"foo\")"`), and allows you to easily move the code from the inline to an external script page.

Comment: `'` and `"` are equivalent in xml too, so you could write `onclick='alert("foo")'` and still be valid. Since languages which do make a distinction often opt for `"` to wrap strings, I tend to stick with that in JS.

Comment: @Douglas: that is exactly correct.  I said "proper" and meant "common".  Fixed - great catch.