# Using jQuery how can I set the contents of a textarea when the value from MySQL contains newlines

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

To keep my code clean I am defaulting each of the elements of a form with jQuery.

i.e My form contains elements like this..

```
<input name="mobile" id="mobile" type="text" />
```

In my separate javascript file, I read data from MySQL, then use jQuery to set it, after the form is loaded..

```
$('#mobile').val('07845 887766');
```

this value is read from MySQL and I generate the code like this, in PHP..

```
echo "\n $('#mobile').val('".$user['mobile']."');";
```

This works fine, but the problem lies when there is a textarea field..

```
<textarea name="notes" id="notes" ></textarea>

echo "\n $('#notes').html('TEST');";
```

This works fine, but when I replace it with the data from a database, which can contain newlines, I get a javascript error.

```
echo "\n $('#notes').html('".$user['notes']."');";
```

This could produce this code (Actual values...)

```
$("#notes").html("INSERT INTO action    (
                    inputdate,
                )
                VALUES ()");
```

Which gives an error.  "unterminated string literal"

Comment: Don't use single quotes and read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript

Comment: If the output is truly as in the last code block, then there shouldn't be any javascript error. Can you double check the contents of `$user['notes']` and update your question with the value?

Comment: Gary: The actual code generated is this (copy and paste - real values)     $("#code").html("INSERT INTO action (
     inputdate,
    )
    VALUES ()");   - The edit box here is not showing carriage returns...   See orignal post...

Comment: Ah I see. Please find amended answer below. It'll fix everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **unterminated string literal**

You're getting this message because in Javascript you can't span literal strings across multiple lines.

What you need to do is replace newlines in `$user['notes']` with the characters `\r\n` so all the string is on **one line** then the `<textarea>` input will correctly show each item on a new line.

Let's use `json_encode` to help us also escape any nasty characters which Javascript won't like.

```
// This will convert to be Javascript friendly. 
// Output string will be enclosed in quotes " "
$notes_str = json_encode($user['notes']);
echo "\n $('#notes').html(" . $notes_str . ");";
```

Answer (score 1):

it could be  single quotes instead of double quotes, try this:

```
echo PHP_EOL.'$("#notes").html("'.$user['notes'].'");';
```

Comment: Unfortunately not.  BTW, the error I get is "unterminated string literal"

Answer (score 0):

Replace your line returns with \n, something like this:

```
echo "\n $('#notes').html('".str_replace("\n","\\n",$user['notes'])."');";
```

php is not my strongest suit, so the syntax may be slightly off.  But basically replace the line returns with the characters "\n".  (may need to handle /r too I guess, or a combination of the two)

EDIT: Apparently if you're using PHP 5.2 or greater you can use `json_encode(` and it will handle quotes and newlines.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using smarty templating engine you can use it like --

```
$('textarea#myTextAreaId').val({$arrVal.keyValue|@json_encode});
```

otherwise its common to face this problem as currently .val() on textarea elements strips carriage return.