# Read data from mysql and pass variable to jquery function, write in a textarea, not work

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, textarea, rows

I am a beginner in jquery. I'm sorry for my english.
I read data from mysql:

```
$id=($row["ID"]);  
$name=($row["Name"]);
$note=($row["Note"]);  *// note set to textarea*
```

send function:

```
onclick= modP($id,$name,$note);

<script>
 function modP(id,name,note){
 $("#NoteP").val(note);
}
</script>
```

----- PROBLEM -------

> NoteP  is textarea.

if $note has one line the function work. all OK.

if $note has many lines the function modP is not called.

I tried with:

```
$note = str_replace("\n","<br />", $row["Note"]);
```

Not work!

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that with htmlspecialchars and json_encode :

```
  $note = htmlspecialchars(json_encode($row["Note"], JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG));
```

...without quotes $note

```
onclick="return modPaziente($note);"
```

....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function modPaziente(note){
    alert(note);
}
```

Thank you all for the suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Try to encode your string to JSON in the PHP part then decode in JS part.

PHP :

```
$note= json_encode($row["Note"]);
```

JS :

```
$("#NoteP").val( JSON.parse(note) );
```

Comment: I have tried as he said, 
 the function modP is not called.

Comment: Add the whole tag where you've `onclick= modP($id,$name,$note);` attribute

Comment: $note=($row["Note"]);
    echo("<td><input name=\"imgmodifica\" id=\"imgmodifica\" type=\"image\" src=\"image/modifica2.png\" width=\"24\" height=\"24\"  title=\"Elimina ".$row["ID_P"]."\" onclick=\"return modPaziente('$id','$nom','$ind','$comID','$citta','$prov','$tel','$cf','$ese','$cons','$nato','$sesso','".$note."','$eta')\"> </input></td>");

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 function 
    modPaziente(id,nom,ind,comID,citta,prov,tel,cf,ese,cons,nato,sesso,note,eta){
    
   
    visPaziente(id,nom,ind,comID,citta,prov,tel,cf,ese,cons,nato,sesso,note,eta);
  enableInput();
 }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function 
    visPaziente(id,nom,ind,comID,citta,prov,tel,cf,ese,cons,nato,sesso,note,eta){
    $("#NoteP").val(note);
    }
    </script>

Comment: I have tried a lot, but it does not work. $note = json_encode($row["Note"], JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG);  -------> modPaziente('".$note."')\"> </input></td>");

Answer (score 0):

use nl2br on $note to break multines as below.

```
$id=$row["ID"];  
$name=$row["Name"];
$note=$row["Note"]; 
$note=nl2br($note);
```

You can call onclick function on your html element as below.

```
<button onClick="modP('<?php echo $id ?>','<?php echo $name ?>','<?php echo $note ?>');">Click</button>
```

And the modP function will be as shown below.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function modP(id,name,note) { 
    $("#NoteP").val(note);;
} 
</script>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, I used   $note=nl2br($note);    but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I found this suggestion
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821268/using-jquery-how-can-i-set-the-contents-of-a-textarea-when-the-value-from-mysql)

Jquery function does not accept variables on multiple lines.

```
$note=str_replace("\n","<br />",$row["Note"]);
```

Now the function is called correctly.
($note) is one line.
How can I write textarea restoring original text, with many lines?

Answer (score 0):

```
$note = json_encode($row["Note"], JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG);   
// note set to textarea - multiline
```

pass $data to the function modPaziente:

```
 echo("<td><input name=\"imgmodifica\" id=\"imgmodifica\" type=\"image\" src=\"image/modifica2.png\" width=\"24\" height=\"24\" title=\"Elimina ".$row["ID_P"]."\" onclick=\"return modPaziente('$id','$nom','$ind','$comID','$citta','$prov','$tel','$cf','$ese','$cons','$nato','$sesso','".$note."','$eta')\"> </input></td>");
```

JS - /* alert(note)  NOT work */

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function modPaziente(id,nom,ind,comID,citta,prov,tel,cf,ese,cons,nato,sesso,note,eta){ 
alert(note); 
} 
</script>
```

why modPaziente does not read note?