# why using javascript escape character of quotation in string need to be \\' instead of \'

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, escaping, quotes

I just having a problems with javascript i am using on code behind on asp.net, after a few hour of figuring it out it turn out to be the problem of escape character.

At first i use this.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "temp", "alert('Can't delete this data because it is bound with rate plan');", true);
```

This will made javascript error because quotation at "can't" need to use escape character so i use.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "temp", "alert('Can\'t delete this data because it is bound with rate plan');", true);
```

but it still not work.

at last i use

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "temp", "alert('Can\\'t delete this data because it is bound with rate plan');", true);
```

and it is fine.

i am just curious why we need to use `\\'` instead of `\'` in order to make escape character works correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\` is an escape character in C# **and** in JavaScript.

When you give C# `"\'"` is creates a string containing an apostrophe.

When you give C# `"\\'"` then the first `\` escapes the second `\` (so the second `\` isn't treated as an escape character) and the `'` is treated as a plain `'` (because the string is not delimited with `'`.

Comment: Thank you for your thoroughly explanation, i will be more careful on an the issue like this.

Answer (score 3):

In a c# string, `\` needs to be escaped, as it is a special prefix for things like `\n` etc. You may find it easier to use a *verbatim strig literal*, which doesn't need escaping (except for `"` to `""`).

For example:

```
@"... can\'t ..."
```

Note the leading `@` *before* the string literal, which indicates the usage of the alternative escaping rules. This also allows newlines etc directly in the string, i.e.

```
@"foo
bar
blip"
```

Answer (score 3):

Because "\" is the escaping character for C# too.

I'd prefer to use @ special operator at the beggining of your string, just before it starts it, because it tells C# that it mustn't process escaping characters.

For example:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "temp", @"alert('Can\'t delete this data because it is bound with rate plan');", true);
```

Anyway, I don't find the point of a single quot. You can avoid escaping this single quot by using double-quot string notation:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "temp", "alert(\"Can't delete this data because it is bound with rate plan\");", true);
```

I don't understand the abuse of single quot in JavaScript if I don't remember there're a lot of PHP coders contributing scripts, since this language behaves in a different way depending of single or double-quoted strings.

Anyway, you can check this other question about single and double-quoting in JavaScript:

- [When to use double or single quotes in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you, I don't have much idea about single quote and double quote, thank you for point out this issue so i can use it more properly next time :)

Comment: Absolutely, I find a bad approach using "advantages" of other languages in JavaScript or any other one if these are useless :) Great to know it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

When you use **\\** it escapes to **\** in the actual javascript which escapes the character. You are essentially escaping twice

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes and apostrophes in names (such as O'Brian) are usually causing trouble in dynamic client scripts, because they'll break them and allow to insert malicious code (aka scripting attacks).

I have written the following **C#6** extension method for code-behind to solve this:

```cs
public static class Extension
{
    public static string ToSQEscapedStringJS<T>(this T unescapedStr)
    {
        if (unescapedStr == null || unescapedStr.ToString() == "")
        {
            return "''";
        }
        // replace ' by @@@
        var escapedStr = (unescapedStr).ToString().Replace("'", "@@@"); 
        // JS code to replace @@@ by '
        string unEscapeSQuote = "replace(/@{3}/g, String.fromCharCode(0x27))"; 
        // add @@@ escaped string with conversion back to '
        return $"('{escapedStr}'.{unEscapeSQuote})"; 
    }
}
```

Its usage is simple. Consider the following dynamic script example:

```cs
// contains apostroph (aka single quote) and is dangerous for your script block
var name = "O'Brian"; 
var nameEscp = name.ToSQEscapedStringJS(); // creates JS expression from it
// building up the script
string strScript = 
   $"<script>window.opener.document.forms(0).{control.Value}.value = {nameEscp};</script>";
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "anything", strScript);
```

**Note** that `nameEscp` is already surrounded by single quote so you can safely place it after the `=`.

The trick is that the string is escaped and upon assignment immediately unescaped (by executing a JavaScript expression) on the fly, i.e.

```cs
.value = ('O@@@Brian'.replace(/@{3}/g, String.fromCharCode(0x27));
```

will be the inserted assignment expression which will be sent to the client as script. After execution, `.value` contains `O'Brian`.