# Add input into form with jquery and submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I want to add an input into form using JQuery, and then submit the form with pure HTML without using javascript.

```
<form method="post" action="" id="myform" >
<input type="hidden" name="example" value="done" />
<input type="submit" value="try" />
</form>
```

Here my JQuery line that add new input:

```
$('#myform').append("<input name="example2" value="done" type='hidden'/>");
```

My issue is when i submit the form, i can't get `example2` input value ! help me to figure it out.

Comment: You need `event.PreventDefault()` then invoke the submit event using `$form.submit()`

Comment: I want to submit the form without using JQuery !

Comment: Are you sure your input is added???

Comment: Yes i verified it ... i changed `hidden` to `text`.

Comment: @BraveType, then kindly, remove `jQuery` tag. Afterwards, `.submit()` method is not exclusive to jQuery library. And, no need for exclamation marks.

Comment: The exclamation marks is because i noticed this in my post :)

Comment: `.submit()` will use the old fashion way of form submission. In other words, in won't use `$.ajax` :)

Comment: Yes, i noticed to don't use `javascript` in order to submit the form, i want it in pure HTML :)

Comment: `i can't get example2 input value` So maybe you can tell us how you are trying to retrieve it?! And post all relevant code in question itself because obviously, this is not the one you have posted (mis-match quoting...)

Comment: like this `$example_two = $_POST["example2"]; echo $example_two;`

Comment: You are doing something wrong but it is not in your posted code as i can see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is download jquery library or use the external google cdn library as the one i have used in my case in the head of your html file.

Ensure that you append the input on the form as the document loads.
If you intend to submit your form to Php as the server side check if the form is posted and print the output.
You should save your file with .php extension.

Try the solution below.
Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("form#myform").append("<input name='example2' value='done' type='hidden'/>")
      })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form method="post" action="" id="myform">
      <input type="hidden" name="example" value="done" />
      <input type="submit" value="try" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the input box failed to append at the end of the form.

You could try inspect element and check if the HTML for the hidden field is generated. Check the quotes:

```
$('#myform').append('<input name="example2" value="done" type="hidden"/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JQuery appears to use double quotes when single should be used:

```
$('#myform').append("<input name='example2' value='done' type='hidden'/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use `""` at the start and at the end of the `()` , inside use `''` . same if you use `''` at the start and at the end of the `()` ,inside use `""`

see more here : [When to use double or single quotes in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript)

or here : [Single or Double quotes in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027986/single-or-double-quotes-in-jquery)

```js
$('#myform').append("<input name='example2' value='done' type='hidden'>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="" id="myform" >
<input type="hidden" name="example" value="done" />
<input type="submit" value="try" />
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is download `jQuery` library or use the external google CDN library as the one I have used in my case in the head of your `html` file.

Ensure that you append the input on the form as the document loads.
If you intend to submit your form to `PHP` as the server side check if the form is posted and print the output. You should save your file with `.php` extension.

Try the solution below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("form#myform").append("<input name='example2' value='done' type='hidden'/>")
      })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form method="post" action="" id="myform">
      <input type="hidden" name="example" value="done" />
      <input type="submit" value="try" />
    </form>
```