# Jquery find input value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to find input value in a string, it should look something like this:

```
var someHtml = "some text, <div id='somediv'></div> <input type='text' value='somethin' />";

$(someHtml).find('input').val();
```

this ofcourse doesn't work so how can i do that?

Comment: Take a good look at the quotes in string your are trying to store in the variable

Comment: Take a look on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/242813/601179) question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to escape the double quotes or use single quotes in `someHtml` string which I don't think so is the same in actual case but still. And instead of using `find` you have to use `siblings` because `input` is the `sibling` inside `$(someHtml)` or wrap the whole `html` inside a `div` and then can use `find` method.

Try this.

```
$(someHtml).siblings('input').val();
```

Alternatively you can use this too.

```
$(someHtml).wrap('<div />').parent().find('input').val();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6yTBv/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

You mixed up the `someHtml` string.
Use `'` for strings inside `"` strings...

```
var someHtml = "some text, <div id='somediv'></div> <input type='text' value='somethin' />";

$(someHtml).find('input').val();
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/242813/601179) question about when to use `"` and when to use `'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can see straight from the SO markup.

**Escape** your quotes!

```
var someHtml = "some text, <div id=\"somediv\"></div> <input type='text' value='somethin' />";

$(someHtml).find('input').val();
```