# Using " or ' in selector strings

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between using this

```
$('.container').text();
```

and this:

```
$(".container").text();
```

both (`"`) and (`'`) work but what's the difference?

Comment: There is no difference, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The long and short of it is that there is ***no difference whatsoever.***

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in this case, you can use either apostrophes (`'`) or quotation marks (`"`) to delimit strings in Javascript.

Where you can see a difference, is when you need to use apostrophes or quotation marks inside a string. If you delimit a string using apostrophes, you have to escape apostrophes inside the string, but not quotation marks, and vice versa.

Example:

```
var html = '<div class="info"></div>';
```

vs.

```
var html = "<div class=\"info\"></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

from my experience, generally no differences.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same, there is no difference, just a coding convenience.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, except for when you want either double or single quotes to appear inside your string:

```
$(".continer[rel='hello']");
```