# escaping quotes from strings using javascript?

Tags: javascript

For instance say I have the string:

```
var name = 'Mc'Obrian'
```

I want to be able to escape the the first quote and the last quote only, not the quote used within the name, how can I achieve this in javascript? thanks

Comment: Sorry, what? "Escape" for which purpose?

Comment: What string do you really have? The whole "`var name = 'Mc'Obrian'`"?

Comment: I have a feeling you'd benefit from reading [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will properly escape the single quote given your current code:

```
var name = 'Mc\'Obrian'
```

I would encourage you to read the [following tutorial about strings](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html). If you are interested in performance considerations, [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript).

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i need function to do it, i don't have control over the strings that im getting from a stream :)

Comment: You should update you question to reflect your full requirements.

Answer (score 1):

use `\` to escape the single quote like so:

```
var name = 'Mc\'Obrian'
```

Answer (score 1):

`var name = 'Mc\'Obrian'`

or

`var name = "Mc'Obrian"`