# Why is it recommended not to use double quote unless we are writing JSON in Node.js Style?

Tags: node.js, coding-style, standards

I came across an interesting [article](http://nodeguide.com/style.html#quotes). Which states unless until we are defining JSON we should use only single quote.

```
var foo = 'bar'; //Right way   

var foo = "bar"; //Wrong way
```

Can anyone put light on this, why is it so?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason is programmer preference / API consistency.

Strictly speaking, there is no difference in meaning; so the choice comes down to convenience.

Here are several factors that could influence your choise:

- House style: Some groups of developers already use one convention or the other.
- Client-side requirements: Will you be using quotes within the strings? (See Ady's answer).
- Server-side language: VB.Net people might choose to use single quotes for java-script so that the scripts can be built server-side (VB.Net uses double-quotes for strings, so the java-script strings are easy to distinguished if they use single quotes).
- Library code: If you're using a library that uses a particular style, you might consider using the same style yourself.
- When using single quotes, any apostrophe needs escaping. (`'Joe\'s got a cool bike.'`) When using double quotes, they don't. (`"Joe's got a cool bike."`) Apostrophes are much more common in English strings than double quotes.
- Personal preference: You might thing one or other style looks better.

Please check following post that might be helpful for you [When to Use Double or Single Quotes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

First of all this is just a style guide.

You can define your `ECMAScript` strings the way you like them.
It is syntactically correct to use single quotes or double quotes for strings.

But according to [`JSON Specifications`](http://www.json.org), a `JSON` value can be a **string in double quotes**, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array.