# Jquery denoted class and id

Tags: jquery

In jquery somebody mention class name  and id with in "" double quotes, somebody denoted in single quotes ''...
what is the difference in these two things.

Comment: both "" and '' are same

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript there is absolutely no difference between double and single quotes. Just a matter of preference.

Comment: aww, beat me to it by a second.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by 'mention class name and id'?

Btw, generally speaking about single and double take a look here:

[When to use double or single quotes in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, you might want to use single quotes when you also want to use the double quotes inside the string, like:

```
<script>

    // Finds all inputs with a name attribute that contains the word 'man' and sets the value with some text.
    $('input[name~="man"]').val('mr. man is in it!');

</script>
```

Other than that, there's no difference between them. Just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

In jquery somebody using class name, id like this $('.someclass') $('#someclass') or $(".someclass") $("#someclass").
So here what is the major difference between in these two things