# Issues with SQL row echoed in to Javascript, error SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

Tags: php, javascript

I am using some facebook post to wall JS, and the information for the post is echoed via php, but i get this error in the console:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal    

description: 'Well, personal favorite in the following order.<br />
```

This is the row for the API call

```
description: '<?php echo $info['definition'] ?>'
```

and this is $info['definition'] string in the SQL database:

```
Well, personal favorite in the following order.

1. A stalkers dream come true

2. The reason most work are never done on time.

See what I mean with the examples.
```

If i use some other string, and type it in directly, it dosnt prompt the script error, how do i escape the string and make it work in the API call?

Comment: Any help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/242813/1169519)?

Comment: You have to remove all white spaces from the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing the following line:

```
description: '<?php echo $info['definition'] ?>'
```

with this:

```
description: "<?php echo preg_replace( '~[\r\n]*~', '', $info['definition'] );?>"
```

Comment: error changed to:  

description: "Well, personal favorite in the following order.&lt;br /&gt;

Comment: Can you please show what are you getting in your html. That would help in debugging. Can you post it to a fiddle so that we could test with it.

Comment: Dont really know how to pass the exact situation to a fiddle, considering the SQL, but i can give you the page of the error
http://www.funkydictionary.com/words/?w=facebook%3D1#

Comment: Sorry, can you remove the `;` from the end of the `description` node...i didn't know it was part of an object.

Comment: I removed the ; and the issue persists :(

Comment: Sorry, i fixed it. Please check my answer again. The issue was newlines.

Comment: Thank you for the help, i accepted the answer to, but there is a new issue lol, now it fails on every other page

Comment: In that case, please see this thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines)

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove all white spaces from the string. Javascript considers all new lines as a new statement.

Comment: FYI white space would include the literal [space], so you don't want to remove whitespace, you want to remove line breaks...