# why onclick not working as expected?

Tags: javascript

I am confused why **onclick** is not wokring

Code1:

```
onclick="return clicked('35','http://www.google.com');"
```

Code2:

```
onclick='return clicked('35','http://www.google.com');'
```

If i used code1 **onclick** works fine but not with code2

thnx

Comment: Looking at the syntax highlighter on Stack Overflow, are you still confused?

Comment: You use simple quotes for the second onclick although you've got simple quotes in it. This works for example even if it is not what you want : onclick='return clicked(35);'

Comment: Just out of interest: why so many down votes?

Comment: @peterp - The question shows (too) little understanding of the problem, and says things like "work" and "not working" without any details (i.e. error message), and honestly is *too* basic - you should know how to escape character by the time you're writing real code. Also, it isn't very interesting. I understand why people voted down.

Comment: To me it seems like a valid beginner question. I'd love to see useful hints like "Have a peek into your Javascript console" or "Use firebug to debug JavaScript problems like this" instead of downvotes.

Comment: That said, @user2619187: Have a peek into your Javascript console or use firebug to easily debug JavaScript problems like this :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to Use Double or Single Quotes in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Because you're breaking out of the onclick too soon, since you use single quotes for multiple things. The first one doesn't break since you can have single quotes in double quotes. If you use the second approach, escape the single quotes in the function call.

Comment: +1 to the only answer that mentions escaping `:)`

Answer (score 1):

It's because of `'` and `"` characters. If you open a `"` and want to put another string inside you need to use `'` or it will close the first one.

That's why the code1 works, you start the string with `"`, then you use `'` to specify parameters so the string isn't closed.

In code2, you start the string with `'` and then use `'` again to specify parameters. So the string you started is closed in the middle of you onclick statement.

code2 would work with :

```
onclick='return clicked("35","http://www.google.com");'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use single quotes for HTML attributes, you need to use double quotes for the Javascript arguments:

```
onclick='return clicked("35","http://www.google.com");'
```

Otherwise the browser is confused and thinks the attribute value is only `return clicked(`