# Closing Tag in HTML / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript in which one of the line is

```
imgtag = '<div style="float:left; padding:0px 10px 5px 0px;"><a expr:href="data:post.url"><img src="'+img[0].src+'" width="218px" height="170px"/></a></div>';
```

In the above code I want `<a expr:href="data:post.url">` to be changed in `<a expr:href='data:post.url'>` but adding this type of closing tag is conflicting with the Javascripts closing tag. What should I do ?

Comment: there is no difference between `'`and `"`

Comment: if you just want to change the type of quote, try escaping: `\'`

Comment: Please [learn about strings in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript), and read [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html#link2) too

Comment: They're not "closing tags", they're string delimiters.

Answer (score 2):

You can escape the single quote like `\'`

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean you want to [escape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) the characters?

If so you will need to include `\'` instead of `"`, and change your code to:

```
imgtag = '<div style="float:left; padding:0px 10px 5px 0px;"><a expr:href=\'data:post.url\'><img src="'+img[0].src+'" width="218px" height="170px"/></a></div>';
```

This will result in the line `expr:href='data:post.url'`

Comment: added but the code still turns into <a expr:href="data:post.url"> after compilation

Answer (score 1):

Escape it with `\'`.

`imgtag = '<div style="float:left; padding:0px 10px 5px 0px;"><a expr:href=\'data:post.url\'><img src="'+img[0].src+'" width="218px" height="170px"/></a></div>';`

Comment: added but the code still turns into <a expr:href="data:post.url"> after compilation

Comment: compilation, by what? the browser? what are you doing with the string following this?

Comment: Yah I added the code in my blogger blog. If the code would have been correct a URL would be generated but it didn't for me. I inspected the HTML via Firebug and save that code.

Comment: I'm not familiar with blogger templating, you might want to ask someone else. Sorry.