# How to use '>' or '&gt' special character in jquery button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to insert > character to button in jquery. I need a button like this "**Continue >**".

```
jQuery("#hello").dialog({
       buttons: {
          Continue&gt: function() {
             jQuery( this ).dialog( "close" );
          }
       }
});
```

I tried Continue&gt:, Continue>: Continue>:, but with no success. Please help me

Comment: Use quotes: `Continue&gt`

Comment: Side-note: `&gt` is NOT a valid HTML entity. Entities MUST end with a `;` (so `&gt;`). Browsers will tolerate the lack of a semicolon, however validators and parsers won't.

Answer (score 4):

You have to quote the button name.

See: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons

Quick ref:

> Specifies which buttons should be displayed on the dialog. The context
>   of the callback is the dialog element; if you need access to the
>   button, it is available as the target of the event object. Multiple
>   types supported: Object: The keys are the button labels and the values
>   are the callbacks for when the associated button is clicked. Array:
>   Each element of the array must be an object defining the attributes,
>   properties, and event handlers to set on the button.

Code:

```
$("#hello").dialog({
       buttons: {
          "Continue>": function() {
             $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          }
       }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cCCMG/1/

Comment: +1, but personally I'd use double-quotes (and quote that "buttons" key too) because I'm picky like that :p

Comment: ARGHHH! Just see it now, fixed :-)

Comment: why double over single quotes?

Comment: this worked.. thanks.. why double quotes over single quotes? Single quotes also worked for me

Comment: They works both, but for code comprehension and for use the same convention is better to use the same char for quote and the other as the literal. More deeply here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript

Comment: @redried Because JSON (a strict subset of object literal syntax) requires double-quotes around object keys.

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote any property names that are not unreserved identifiers.

```
jQuery("#hello").dialog({
       buttons: {
          "Continue>": function() {
             jQuery( this ).dialog( "close" );
          }
       }
});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The problem is with general JavaScript syntax, as stated in the answer. There is no need to “escape” the character “>” in a JavaScript string constant, but the string must be written in quotatuon marks.

Answer (score 0):

You can quote the text for the button name but that still won't let you use HTML character entities. You can however do this:

```
$('.ui-button-text').append(' &raquo;');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/c34tS/1/)**

Comment: In addition to being unnecessarily complicated, this approach adds a wrong character (“›” and not “>”),

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - I used that character simply as an example of a character that doesn't have a simple keyboard replacement like >. And please explain to us all how my one line solution is "unnecessarily complicated".

Comment: The question was about “>”, and not even a one-liner fix is needed when the name `'Continue >'` is properly quoted.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, since you mentioned HTML character entities, you can use [Octal character codes](http://www.pjb.com.au/comp/diacritics.html) in your button's text:

**HTML**

```
<div id='hello'>hello world</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#hello").dialog({
   buttons: {
     "Continue \273": function() { // Note the escaped '273' (open/close chevron-style quotes)
       $(this).dialog("close");
     }
   }
});
```

**[Codepen example](http://cdpn.io/FlngL)**

Comment: Octal escape sequences are non-standard and explicitly disallowed in strict mode.  http://es5.github.io/#B.1.2 says "The syntax and semantics of 7.8.4 can be extended as follows except that this extension is not allowed for strict mode code..."