# Javascript comparing boolean value to True

Tags: javascript

I am trying to compare a database (SQL) value (which is being returned correctly) to the boolean value 'true'. If the database bit value is = true then I want a div element to become visible, else stay hidden.

```
<script language="javascript">
    window.onload= function show_CTL() {
        if(<%=_CurrentUser.IsCTL%> == true){
            document.getElementById('CTL').style.visibility = "visible";
        } else{
            document.getElementById('CTL').style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }    
</script>
```

However I am getting the error, Javascript: 'True' is undefined.

I have tried many combinations of <%=_CurrentUser.IsCTL%>  == 'true' or "true" or true or  "True" or 'true' and even the === ... but all give me the same error message.

Any insights on how to resolve this issue will be greatly appreciated.

I have such comparisons successfully before with integer values such as:-

```
 window.onload= function show() {
    if(<%=_CurrentUser.RoleKey%> == 1 || <%=_CurrentUser.RoleKey%> == 2)
            document.getElementById('enr').style.visibility = "visible";
    else
            document.getElementById('enr').style.visibility = "hidden";
 }
```

Comment: What language is `<%=_CurrentUser.IsCTL%>` and what does it output?

Comment: it outputs true or false (boolean) values. appropriately for currently logged in user.

Comment: @j08691, it is asp.net I suppose

Comment: Try `if("<%=_CurrentUser.IsCTL%>" == "True")` or `if(<%=_CurrentUser.IsCTL.ToString().ToLower()%> == true)`

Comment: What dose the code look like when it's sent to the browser? You're probably getting `True == true`, hence your error. `True` is an undefined variable in JS, `true` is a boolean value...

Comment: The lhs of your equal is inserting the four letters `True`. Try enclosing them in quotes to make it a string and comparing them to the string "True".

Comment: a tip: always enclose the jsp expr in quotes as "<%=_CurrentUser.IsCTL%>", since if it empty string then it will be if(==true) which is a wrong syntax and might fail in this scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this:

```
if("<%=_CurrentUser.IsCTL%>" === "True")
```

`<%=_CurrentUser.IsCTL%>` is returning `True`. So wrap it with string and compare them instead. Notice the '===' instead of '=='.

Comment: Hi Amit, as mentioned in my statement, that doesn't work. I have tried some possible combinations and I have mentioned them in my question.

Comment: @Philo, you didn't see my answer properly. I'm wrapping both with strings

Comment: Why you use single and double quotes? Why not both single or both double?

Comment: @martijnn2008, it doesn't matter ;)

Comment: @martijnn2008 check this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript

Comment: I though it would not make a difference, but I do expect some consistency, so that is why I asked for a particular reason.

Comment: One more problem :- even the return value is true, the condition for false always gets evaluated...

Answer (score 2):

In

```
if(<%=_CurrentUser.IsCTL%> == true)
```

I think `<%=_CurrentUser.IsCTL%>` is getting evaluated to True before the code is seen by the browser.
The browser will see this as

```
if(True == true)
```

`True` does not make a lot of sense to the browser, thats why the error. For this true to be treated as a boolean, try one of this:

```
if(new Boolean('<%=_CurrentUser.IsCTL%>') == true)
```

or

```
if(new Boolean('<%=_CurrentUser.IsCTL%>'))
```

Comment: That doesn't work the way you think it does... `(new Boolean("False")) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"` evaluates to... `"TRUE"`

Comment: @thebjorn you are right. Confused Java's behaviour with Javascript's behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

This has gotten me before as well. ASP.NET will return `True` for a boolean which is true. You have to make it a string and then compare it to the string version `== "True"` in order to get a proper conditional statement.

Conversely, you could also just make a variable in javascript

```
var True = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your native boolean value to the string "true" before output. So, assuming ASP.NET MVC, I believe it looks like:

```
<%=_CurrentUser.IsCTL ? "true" : "false"%>
```