# Using protractor to open file url with Firefox

Tags: javascript, selenium, firefox, jasmine, protractor

Currently I am attempting to (force) use Protractor access a file as a website (an html file).  When I attempt to do so, an error from protractor which reads:

```
    Failed: Access to 'file:///C:/filelocation/index.html' from script denied
    Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'
    System info: host: 'BAHCND4397GQF', ip: '10.138.1.189', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64',os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_72'
    Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

After searching the internet for a solution I found the issue was a Firefox one with the simple instructions of adding:

```
    user_pref("capability.policy.policynames", "localfilelinks");
    user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.sites", "C:/MendisSoftwareList/Software%20List/cwmdt-applications-parent/common-parent/index.html");
    user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.checkloaduri.enabled", "allAccess");
```

to a 'user.js' file.  After more research I have found that this file must be in the Firefox Profile I am attempting to use which I have placed in the location:

```
    C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\Profile
```

to no avail.  Quite frankly I am out of ideas.  Any help would be appreciated.
Here is the list of my resources:

```
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/selenium-users/Guh9x4HEWls/pbEjrsq5pXUJ
http://kb.mozillazine.org/User.js_file
https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/6373
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean you need to open your url using firefox? If then try  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'firefox',
  }

Comment: I am currently using Firefox and my browser does open with it.  However it crashes immediately after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a partial answer to this question here: [Opening a file with protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24824491/opening-a-file-with-protractor)

Which serves my needs and accomplishes my goals.

However, I would like to hear a more in-depth answer for my own purposes and that of the community so any and all other questions and comments please feel free to leave another answer or just leave in the comments.

Thanks