# "host" a file on a specific URL for testing

Tags: javascript, selenium, jasmine, protractor, karma-runner

I want to run UI tests on my pure **vanilla ES5 JS** (not Angular, and no modules, important for the rest I suppose) web page but, for that, I need to it on a specific URL (set a hostname and port, and other).

I use Jasmine and Karma for my unit test and run them automatically on **Travis CI**.

Now I reached the point where I want have functional/UI tests. For that, Protractor, in combination with Selenium, was recommended. But I'm encountering various problems (and I'm not even close to trying to incorporate it to Travis CI).

### Short version

I have a local file `index.html` and, in order for it to properly initialise, it requires a specific URL ("`<protocole, mostly http>://<some-host>:<port>/<some-path>/index.html?<some-query>`").

I can currently access the `index`, but only "locally" ("`file:///<path-to-local-project>/index.html?<query>`") and therefore am only able to test the error use case where URL is malformed (hey, at least that's one of the tests).

**I need a way to host/say "`file:///<path-to-local-project>/index.html?<query>`" is accessed via "`http://<some-host>:<port>/<some-path>/index.html?<query>`"** because, when integrated to the full program, the page will be hosted somewhere and the URL contains valuable information for dynamic behaviors *(really have no idea which keyword to use there ("host", "route"... ?) nor am I even certain this is to be configured in protractor or actually have to prepare some kind of hosting script just for testing. And keep in mind that, in the end, I want to be able to run these on Travis CI too)*

### What I have

In `protractor.conf.js`

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',

  baseUrl: 'file:///' + __dirname,

  onPrepare: function(){
    /**
     * If you are testing against a non-angular site - set ignoreSynchronization setting to true
     *
     * If true, Protractor will not attempt to synchronize with the page before
     * performing actions. This can be harmful because Protractor will not wait
     * until $timeouts and $http calls have been processed, which can cause
     * tests to become flaky. This should be used only when necessary, such as
     * when a page continuously polls an API using $timeout.
     *
     * @type {boolean}
     */
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

    global.dv = browser.driver;
    // By default, Protractor use data:text/html,<html></html> as resetUrl, but
    // location.replace from the data: to the file: protocol is not allowed
    // (we'll get ‘not allowed local resource’ error), so we replace resetUrl with one
    // with the file: protocol (this particular one will open system's root folder)
    browser.resetUrl = 'file://';
  },

  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

  specs: [
    'test/protractor/**/*.spec.js',
  ],

  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    /*
    proxy: {
      proxyType: 'manual',
      httpProxy: 'localhost:69/ID-420'
    }, //*/
    chromeOptions: {
      // --allow-file-access-from-files - allow XHR from file://
      args: ['allow-file-access-from-files']
    }
  }
};
```

In `spec.js`

```
describe('The main page', function () {

  beforeEach(function () {
    // jasmine.Ajax.install();  // how I intercept http requests in the unit tests. Here I may need another package apparently
    console.log("browser", browser);
    dv.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  });
  /*
  afterEach(function () {
    jasmine.Ajax.uninstall();
  });
  // */

  it('should display an error message in the alert if no parameters are provided', function () {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.get('/index.html');

    element(by.className('ajs-content')).getText().then(console.log);
    browser.sleep(5000);
    expect(element(by.className('ajs-content')).getText()).toEqual("No ID or Host detected");
    // expect(element(by.className('ajs-content')).getText()).toEqual(new EXCEPTIONS.NoHostOrIdInURI().description); // not working because unable to import scripts without **modules** (since ES5) but np, I can hard code the expected result
    browser.getCurrentUrl().then(console.log);
  });
});
```

Yes, this works, but if I can't set a custom URL for the file, I cannot test any other use case... And the topics I find online often are in Angular.

[Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56751624/imports-in-vanilla-pure-js-testing-with-protractor-and-relative-paths) (way too vague) but maybe contain additional infos.

Comment: My initial guesses were either the `proxy` attribute of Protractor or start a node server to host the file beforehand, something like `http-server --port <port>` though in this last case, I'd need to have a "fake" path between `./` and `index.html` without having to create a folder (the path needs to verify a certain regex expression too for the initialisation to proceed)

Comment: Why do you need a fake path? Not sure I understand...

Comment: @tehbeardedone because the page seeks for specific parameters (not just query, the host and some elements of the path too) to properly initialise. When deployed, this page is included in a "local server" I guess and the URL then looks like "<protocol>://<some-host>:<port>/<some-path>/index.html?<some-query>"