# Javascript 'case' vs "case"

Tags: javascript, syntax, switch-statement

I'm learning about switches in Javascript, and whenever I add a case, I'm not sure whether to use single quotation marks or double quotation marks.

```
switch(answer)
{
    case 'hello':
        console.log("Hello there!");
        break;
}
```

vs

```
switch(answer)
{
    case "hello":
        console.log("Hello there!");
        break;
}
```

Note that in the line with the case, I put double quotation marks instead of single quotation marks on the second example. Which one is correct?

Comment: Doesn't matter imho. Both are correct. More a matter of preference than anything else.

Comment: In many languages, Javascript may be excluded, single quotes are usually used to denote characters, not strings. In some languages like Perl, single quoted strings will take everything inside the quotes as literal, in that you cannot expand variables. I would say use double-quotes just to keep in line with what they are generally used to represent; strings.

Comment: if you have single quotes in your string use double, and vise versa, otherwise there is no other difference

Comment: Does not matter in Javascript as long as you don't mix and match. ``"a string"`` is same as ``'a string'`` but ``"a 'string'"`` is not same as ``'a "string"'``

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript

Comment: It´s not because it is like that in javascript that it´s the right way. A string always should have double quotes, e.g. "string". Single quotes are used for characters, e.g. 'A'. And yea Javascript doesnt obey these rules, but that is because javascript is not a programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do whatever you like. String literals in JavaScript are written with either single quotes or double qoutes. It doesn't matter.

`case 'hello':` will be the same as `case "hello":`, just as `console.log('Hello there!')` will be the same as `console.log("Hello there!")`