# Parse cloud function define

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

My question is about the first line of parse cloud function. 
for example, this function is copy from parse docs:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) { 
   if (!request.object.get("email")) {
   response.error("email is required for signup");
   } else {
   response.success();
  }
});
```

The Parse.User is a parse predefined class. Does that mean this cloud function will be automatically executed when saving a object in this class?

Another question is also about the class. here are two examples of parse cloud function from parse example app Anypic and Parse docs:

```
 Parse.Cloud.beforeSave('Activity', function(request, response) {
   var currentUser = request.user;
   var objectUser = request.object.get('fromUser');
   if(!currentUser || !objectUser) {
   response.error('An Activity should have a valid fromUser.');
  } else if (currentUser.id === objectUser.id) {
   response.success();
  } else {
   response.error('Cannot set fromUser on Activity to a user other than the current user.');
  }
});


  Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Review", function(request, response) {
    if (request.object.get("stars") < 1) {
    response.error("you cannot give less than one star");
    } else if (request.object.get("stars") > 5) {
     response.error("you cannot give more than five stars");
    } else {
    response.success();
  }
});
```

What's the difference between these two cloud function in the first line: the Activity is quoted in single quotation marks but the Review is quoted in double quotation marks. Are they all stands for some parse subclass or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your original question: Yes, the function with signature:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response)
```

will be executed before every Parse.User class object is saved.

To answer your next question, those two examples are equivalent.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript
```

They do pre-save stuff for the Activity and Review classes respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the link. So it means i can use either double or single quotation marks to define a parse subclass. Is my understanding right?