# Please Explain with performance effect which one better for use

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

What is Difference between

```
'@Url.Action("MethodName", "ControllerName")'
```

and

```
"@Url.Action("MethodName", "ControllerName")"
```

Comment: I don't see a difference

Comment: Nothing (I assume you use this in javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are same, it's most likely a preference even though I suggest you to keep the consistency.

[When to use double or single quotes in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript)