# JQuery - Difference between " " and ' ' when Selecting Element from HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, difference

I ve been learning JQuery, and everything was clear. Until I reached the strings.
So far I knew that when you want to call something you do it this way `$('callSomething')`. Now Im learning how to move html elements around, and it was written to call something with double comment lines `$("callSomething")`.

I started playing around the code, and I ve noticed that no matter what I will use `' '` or `" "` the code will work.

```
     $('#one').after("<p>test</p>");
    var $p = $("p");
    $("#two").after($p)
```

Now I'm not sure what to use where. I understand that `" "` is used to call Strings. But I could use it to call elements too.

My question:
Is there a specific reason when to use `' '`? Or should I always use `" "` since its working and save myself the confusion?

Any explanation maybe on when to use `' '` and when '" "`(if there is actual difference between them other than calling a string`("< .p>test<./ p >")`?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Hope this can help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript

Comment: This is about JavaScript syntax. It's not specific to jQuery or any other JavaScript library.

Comment: It is not a duplicate question. The other question is asking about how Quotes work in strings.
My question is about Selecting Elements from html.
I will edit the question

Answer (score 1):

This can help,

I wouldn't say there is a preferred method, you can use either. However If you are using one form of quote in the string, you might want to use the other as the literal.

```
alert('Say "Hello"');
alert("Say 'Hello'");
```

The most likely reason is programmer preference / API consistency.

[When to use double or single quotes in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript)

Comment: Copying information from another answer and then linking to that answer is usually not a good idea.  Instead you should comment that the question is a duplicate (until you have enough rep to close vote).

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the two versions of strings except this one:

Imagine you want to use a quotation mark inside a string:

```
"This is just a lil' test"
```

Or:

```
'"give them hell", he said'
```

You don't have to escape quotation marks in those two cases.

Comment: So $('div).fadeOut() and $("div").fadeOut() are exactly the same...
Thank you very much :)
I was worried that I was doing something wrong. It seems though that many JQuery programmers prefer the single Quote when they select an element from html.

Answer (score 0):

Both are equivalent, it's mainly a matter of preference and code legibility. If your string contains a single quote, you'll probably want to enclose it in double quotes and vice versa, so you don't have to escape your quotes, e.g.

`"It's nice"` vs `'It\'s nice'`

or

`'And she said "Oh my God"'` vs `"And she said \"Oh my God\""`

You can find a more exhaustive answer to that question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/242833/4604579

Answer (score -2):

in javascript there is no difference. in other languages like c, ' will be used for characters and " will be used for character arrays aka strings.

Comment: There is a difference when using single/double quotes inside other single/double quotes.

Comment: thats solved by escaping. in javascript there is NO difference between " and ' except you need to follow the rules of escaping ' inside ' and " inside ".. wich is obvious.