# Add value to href as a var

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add a value to href by adding a var. But it looks like i've got a syntax error somewhere. And can't figure out what's wrong.

```
var abra = "whatever";
$("a.confsbmt").attr('href','http://example.com/example2"+abra+"');
```

Comment: `+` is the string concatenation operator. Make sure you match the quotes. `'http://example.com/example2' + abra`

Comment: your quotes are mis-matched (singles/doubles)

Comment: Correct usage: http://stackoverflow.com/a/242833/1074519

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string begins in single quotes so should end in single quotes to concatenate anything else on, if you want to use double quotes start with double quotes.

```
$("a.confsbmt").attr('href','http://example.com/example2'+abra);
```

Comment: This would be more helpful with an explanation.

Comment: what about in the middle of url?

Comment: middle? you have the base url "http://example.com/example2" then add on abra (+abra)

Comment: what if let's say example.com/example2?"+abra+"somethingelse

Comment: then the second half would also have quotes. Ex: 'www.something.com/somewhere/'+abra+'/otherStuff'