# Print into html with jQuery and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this code to show some html from a db :

```
$("#menuOverlay").append('<?php include('aggiungiPaginaComp.php');?>');
```

It's working, the source file from the browser :

```
$("#menuOverlay").append('<form id="aggiungiPagina"
name="aggiungiPagina"
action="script/aggiungiPagina.php"
method="post">

<tablestyle="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>NomePagina</td>
        <td><inputsize="30"
            maxlength="30"
            placeholder="Inseriscinomepagina"
            autofocus
            required
            type="text"
            name="nomePagina"
            id="nomePagina"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Descrizione</td>
        <td><inputsize="50"
            maxlength="200"
            placeholder="Inseriscidescrizione"
            required
            type="text"
            name="descrizione"
            id="descrizione"></td>
    </tr>

</table>
<divid="scrisciaBtnForm">
    <inputclass="btnMenu"type="submit"value="invia"/>
</div>
</form>');
```

But the div #menuOverlay is blank.. with :

```
$("#menuOverlay").append('<Button> ciao </Button>');
```

works, why?
sorry for bad english.

Comment: Why are you appending contents like that instead of just rendering it with php?

Comment: beacuse the content of the div will change

Comment: One thing that I can spot in the first line is that you're using single quotes inside of single quotes. You'd need to escape those or use double quotes inside of the single quotes instead.

Comment: @IndigoIdentity I do not think it matters here.

Comment: @QuentinRoy `append('<?php include('aggiungiPaginaComp.php');?>')` how so?

Comment: I believe it's about the *new lines* in string. Normally, you'll get an error in console.

Comment: @IndigoIdentity Because <?php stuff ?> will execute stuff in a whole different environment.

Comment: i have repleace the single quotes : $("#menuOverlay").append("<?php include('aggiungiPaginaComp.php');?>"); but don't works anyway..

Comment: @AlessandroZago Sorry, I do not think that this was the solution but just an oddity, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript

Comment: the console error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: @QuentinRoy Yes but he is appending a string... Is `''''` syntactically correct in this case?

Comment: It is an invalid javascript string without escaping new lines.

Comment: @IndigoIdentity The php code will be executed whatever is around it and will replace it anyway.

Comment: @IndigoIdentity What matters is what replaces it.

Comment: Simple solution would be change it to an ajax request

Comment: The content of the div will change how? What you are currently doing is not changing anything. It's static because you you a php include

Comment: now works, the problem is the "new line" \ so i have add a \ at the and of every line

Comment: @PeeHaa I think he means that the insertion may not be performed after the page loading but later depending on what the user does.

Comment: @AlessandroZago Add an answer if you have been able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

For once, you have a lot of invalid HTML, things like `<tablestyle="width:100%;">` - I assume that somehow you have lost a lot of spaces in tags (maybe due to a RegEx?) which destroys the HTML you are trying to insert.

And you can't just have multiline strings in JS. You need to either append a `\` at every newline or replace `\n` to make it a string concatenation:

```
$("#menuOverlay").append('<form id="aggiungiPagina" '+
'name="aggiungiPagina" '+
'action="script/aggiungiPagina.php" '+
'method="post"> '+
' '+
'<table style="width:100%;"> '+
'    <tr> '+
'        <td>NomePagina</td> '+
'        <td><input size="30" '+
'            maxlength="30" '+
'            placeholder="Inseriscinomepagina" '+
'            autofocus '+
'            required '+
'            type="text" '+
'            name="nomePagina" '+
'            id="nomePagina"></td> '+
'    </tr> '+
'    <tr> '+
'        <td>Descrizione</td> '+
'        <td><input size="50" '+
'            maxlength="200" '+
'            placeholder="Inseriscidescrizione" '+
'            required '+
'            type="text" '+
'            name="descrizione" '+
'            id="descrizione"></td> '+
'    </tr> '+
' '+
'</table> '+
'<div id="scrisciaBtnForm"> '+
'    <input class="btnMenu" type="submit" value="invia"/> '+
'</div> '+
'</form>');
```

See here: https://jsbin.com/vidajohevi/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

You should HTML encode the page in PHP (so your double quotes wont cause errors) and then html decode it in JS. If your using jQuery this should work:

```html
String.prototype.htmlDecode = function(){
  return $('<div/>').html(this).text();
};

$("#menuOverlay").append("<?php
    ob_start();
    include('aggiungiPaginaComp.php');
    $page = ob_get_clean();
    echo htmlentities($page);
?>".htmlDecode());
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
 <tablestyle="width:100%;">
```

should be:

```
<table style="width:100%;">
```

Similarly, this:

```
<divid="scrisciaBtnForm">
```

should be:

```
<div id="scrisciaBtnForm">
```

Lastly, remove all new lines in aggiungiPaginaComp.php. Javascript is going to have a problem with new lines when you use it in this manner.