# How to flush nodejs child_process stdin.write

Tags: node.js

I need to run a 'C' program for a client on the server side. this program can be interactive.
I am using  Node.js child_process class. But I see a problem here : since I need to keep the program interactive there will be message exchanged back and forth between client and node.js server .

1.program says : Enter value of x :
send this message to client and get some value as input
2. When the Nodejs server receives the input from client it does   child_process.stdin.write

But the problem is that the program does not execute until I mark the end of the stream. What could be a work around for this ?
Like flushing the values to the program as and when available from the user.

Update :

test1.c
    #include

```
int main() {

int x, y;

printf("Enter x : ");
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%d", &x);

printf("Enter y : ");
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%d", &y);

printf("Value entered y is %d\n", y);
printf("Value entered x is %d", x);
}
```

Compile the above code to generate the executable a.out

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var count = 0;
var exec = spawn('./a.out');


exec.on('error', function (err){
   console.log("Error" + err );
});

exec.stdout.on('data', function(data){
    console.log("in stdout.on.data : " + data.toString());
    if (count == 0) {
        exec.stdin.write('44\n');
        count++;
    }
    else if (count == 1) {
        exec.stdin.write('54');
        count++;
    }
    if (count == 2) {
        exec.stdin.end();
    }

});

exec.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log("in stderr.on.data : " + data);
});

exec.on('close', function (code) {
    if (code != 0) {
        console.log("Program ended with a error code : " + code);
    }

});
```

in the above node.js code if I comment  `exec.stdin.end();` it does not work and it waits until the stream is closed. How can I work around this ? since I want clients to have a continuous interaction it will be difficult for me to predict when to end the stream.

Comment: could you include your source code in your question?

Comment: I found the solution. Since there was no carriage return for exec.stdin.write('54'); the program waited for the scanf. Solution was to add '\n' to the write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to "press Enter".

```
exec.stdin.write('54' + "\n");
OR
exec.stdin.write("54\n");
```

You also can lookup a bit about [Quotes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript)

Comment: I had already answered the question in the comment section :)