# Exclusive use of Template Literals in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-literals

I discovered the interesting possibilities of template literals with ES6 and I was wondering: apart from browsers compatibility, is there any possible 'limitation' of using ONLY template literally for any scenario when dealing with strings?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37777677/5768908

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We successfully use it in every location except `import` statements with Babel. It will throw an error there.

It makes it nice for extending code to drop in variables, much like always wrapping single parameter fat arrow functions with `(` `)` does.

We thought the same thing you did, and began using it everywhere instead of `'` and it works. We also checked the MDN and there is nothing saying you can't use it, but it has some quirks such as indenting `console.log`s by preserving characters, but the short answer is JavaScript and 99% of libraries don't care about spaces or linebreaks, so its not necessary until you get into a wild use case.

**Edit**

We have since converted to use `eslint-config-airbnb` which by default, enforces usage of single quotations for everything, except JSX (which is double quote). It also enforces grave accents only when using template literals.

I consider this config fairly defacto-standard and its ruleset is extremely well-informed and backed by reason. I would recommend setting your proverbial clocks to it.

If you have any questions, definitely create an issue in the [Airbnb GitHub](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb). Target any questions to `ljharb`.