# Single quote or Double quote in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I am learning Nodejs from scratch and I would like to make it a habit of using either single quote or double quote in Node.js. I read few answers elsewhere in Stackoverflow which said that it's purely dependent on the coding style used by the team.

So, which one should I use? Or rather, which one does the expert programmers use? in Apis and elsewhere.

Comment: It simply depends of developer code style, and primarily opinion-based. For example i use single quotes

Comment: Looks like Google suggests using single quotes instead of double quotes too. https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should use single quote. In javascript it is most common to use single quote. Also when you use the eslint, it will show error when using double quote. So, better practice is to use single quote. And, finally it depends on your coding style.

Comment: eslint can be configured to use double quotes instead, so it's not the case