# How to override read RESX file event?

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm facing single quote (') issue inside RESX files while I call them directly in JavaScript, such as:

```
var hello = '<%=SomeTextFromResxWithSingleQuote%>';
```

In this case all the JavaScript is mixed up and many bugs appear :(
Any fast solution to solve this?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
string fixedText = ReplaceSingleQuote("L'df'ds");

public static ReplaceSingleQuote(string text)
{
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            return text;
        }
        return text.Replace("'", "&apos;");
}
```

Comment: No need for thos, you can simply use double quotes to delimit text. See my answer.

Comment: It may be a better idea to escape quote instead of replacing it to `&apos;` since escaped string can be used anywhere, and `&apos;` is only acceptable for HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can use double quotes to skip this issue such as:

```
var hello = "<%=SomeTextFromResxWithSingleQuote%>";
```

JavaScript allows you to use either double or single quotes to delimit text.

[When to use double or single quotes in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript)