# Convert normal array into an object

Tags: javascript

I have this normal array

```
["Company="Google",Country="USA",Id="123"", "Company="Volvo",Country="SWEDEN",Id="999""]
```

And I would like to build an object out of its values.

Expected result is

```
  {
    "root": [{
            "Company": "Google",
            "Country": "USA",
            "Id": "123"
        }, {
            "Company": "Volvo",
            "Country": "SWEDEN",
            "Id": "999"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I work this structure in JavaScript?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "JSON object". JSON is a string format.

Comment: Your "normal array" is a syntax error (as is your expected result). Please show what you actually have.

Comment: What console? Can you post a screenshot? And what's the code that prints to the console?

Comment: @melpomene var request = 'CREATE Car(Company="Google",Country="USA",Id="123"), CREATE Car(Company="Volvo",Country="SWEDEN",Id="999")';

var result = request.match(/\(([^)]+)\)/g);
console.log(result);

Comment: That returns `['CREATE Car(Company="Google",Country="USA",Id="123"', ', CREATE Car(Company="Volvo",Country="SWEDEN",Id="999"']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the array you posted is not valid we'll need to [mix single and double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript) like this:

```
['Company="Google",Country="USA",Id="123"', 'Company="Volvo",Country="SWEDEN",Id="999"']
```

if you're getting the array as a response from a request and you copied it from console than it quotes must've been escaped using `\"` and you don't have to fix it.

**converting the array into an object:**

```
var myArray = ['Company="Google",Country="USA",Id="123"', 'Company="Volvo",Country="SWEDEN",Id="999"']
var myObject = array2obj(myArray);

function array2obj(myArr) {
    var myObj = {root:[]}
    myArr.forEach(function(v) {
        var currentObj = {}
        v.split(",").forEach(function(vi) {
            var tmp = vi.replace(/\"/g, "").split("=");
            currentObj[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
        });
        myObj.root.push(currentObj);
    });
    return myObj
}
```

as you can see you call the function like this `var myObject = array2obj(myArray)` assuming your array is stored in `myArray`.

now you have your object in the variable `myObject`:

```
{
    "root": [
        {
            "Company": "Google",
            "Country": "USA",
            "Id": "123"
        },
        {
            "Company": "Volvo",
            "Country": "SWEDEN",
            "Id": "999"
        }
    ]
}
```

**"reducing" the array into ids only:**

as asked in comments, the following will produce a `newArray` = `["123", "999"]`

```
var myArray = ['Company="Google",Country="USA",Id="123"', 'Company="Volvo",Country="SWEDEN",Id="999"'];

var newArray = myArray.map(function(x) {
    var id = /,\s*id\s*=\s*"(.*?)"/gi.exec(x);
    if (id) return id[1]
});
```

I'm using regex to match the id and [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array with the matched results.

if you want the array to contain numbers and not strings replace `return id[1]` with `return Number(id[1])` but you have to make sure ids are always numbers or you will get `NaN` errors

Comment: no problem at all, if you have any question about the methods used. don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: what if i only want to get the ID values from the array and put them in another array like {123,999}. how to approach it? @Maher

Comment: I think you mean `["123","999"]`,  right? I added the answer