# How to put "" inside a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

I need to put the following line `count_scalar(container_memory_usage_bytes{image!=""} > 0)` inside a string so I did `"count_scalar(container_memory_usage_bytes{image!=""} > 0)"` but it seems not work because there are `""` inside `"..."`

So how can I correct this line ?

Comment: You single quotes,' ' so: `'count_scalar(container_memory_usage_bytes{image!=""} > 0)'`

Comment: Also [When to use double or single quotes in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript).

Comment: Yes sorry I haven't noticed this one has been asked. my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In ES5:**

Well you could put single quotes

```
"count_scalar(container_memory_usage_bytes{image!=''} > 0)"
```