# Why my script returns 'Missing ) after argument list.'?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can you please help me with the following code? I'm getting the error :

```
'missing ) after argument list. (line 18, file "ImportNomPlat")'
```

My code :

```
function Import_NomPlat() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet =  ss.getSheetByName('PLANNING PROD');
    var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]                        


     for (var k= 0; k<array.length; k++) {    

     var destRow = array[k];  

     var destCol = 2;    
     var checkCell = sheet.getRange(destRow,destCol);

     sheet.getRange(destRow, destCol).setFormula('=index(importrange('Feuilles de référence'!$B$2;"'VLOOKUP RECETTES'!A:Z"); \
                                                 EQUIV(A5;importrange('Feuilles de référence'!$B$2;"'VLOOKUP RECETTES'!A:A");0);\
                                                 EQUIV(B$4;importrange('Feuilles de référence'!$B$2;"'VLOOKUP RECETTES'!$A$1:$Z$1");0)'); 


     };
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when trying to add code back into cleared sheet using Set Formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44658368/error-when-trying-to-add-code-back-into-cleared-sheet-using-set-formula)

Answer (score 1):

You've got some problems with quotes and double quotes. Take a look at this previous [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44658368/error-when-trying-to-add-code-back-into-cleared-sheet-using-set-formula/44658584#44658584).

Comment: Yes quotes and double quotes was the problem, thanks

Comment: Then you can mark the answer as accepted, so people going throught the same issue will find easily a fix.