# Javascript on click parameter

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a situation wherein I wanted to use single quote sign `'` inside a parameter.

Below is the code I am trying to work out :

```
<a onclick="toggle_visibility('Wi O' Prestige Condominiums');"></a>
```

Due to `'` sign it not getting executed. But its necessary for me to use `'` sign as it's dynamically coming from other variable

Comment: `toggle_visibility('Wi O\' Prestige Condominiums')` or `toggle_visibility("Wi O' Prestige Condominiums")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use double or single quotes in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript)

Comment: Remember kids, search is your friend: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+quotes

Comment: Wi O' Prestige Condominiums :- this is coming dynamic.. I can not change it.. That's the whole problem

Answer (score 2):

You could escape the single quote `'` using backslash `\` :

```
<a onclick="toggle_visibility('Wi O\' Prestige Condominiums');"></a>
```

Or toggle the location of single/double quotes :

```
<a onclick='toggle_visibility("Wi O' Prestige Condominiums");'></a>
```

Hope this helps.