# Remove single quotes from beginning and end of string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, cxml-commercexml

I'm trying to remove single quotations from a raw text variable and post via AJAX.

I'm getting this error on return from the API endpoint: `Invalid document: Content is not allowed in prolog`.

This error is caused when your XML POST data is preceded by a `""` or `''` usually as is the case with mine. So all you have to do is remove the first and last `""` or `''` with some simple regex and `.trim` or `.replace`.

For whatever reason, it's not removing it for me. I have tried countless regex examples online that supposedly trim the first and last character, only the first and last character if they are `""` or `''` without any success.

Code:

```
$('#idealMatBtn').click(function (e) {
    var xmlSTR = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
               + '<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.014/cXML.dtd">'
                 + '<cXML timestamp="2015-06-12T08:30:00" xml:lang="en-US">'
                   + '<Header>'
                     + '<From>'
                       + '<Credential domain="NetworkID">'
                         + '<Identity>EU019985</Identity>'
                       + '</Credential>'
                     + '</From>'
                     + '<To>'
                       + '<Credential domain="DUNS">'
                         + '<Identity>Ideal Supply Test</Identity>'
                       + '</Credential>'
                     + '</To>'
                     + '<Sender>'
                       + '<Credential domain="NetworkID">'
                         + '<Identity>Ideal Supply Test</Identity>'
                         + '<SharedSecret>Ideal</SharedSecret>'
                       + '</Credential>'
                       + '<UserAgent>eProcurement-System 1.0</UserAgent>'
                     + '</Sender>'
                   + '</Header>'
                   + '<Request>'
                     + '<PunchOutSetupRequest operation="create">'
                       + '<BuyerCookie>[Unique-Generated-Identifier-from-eProcurement-System]</BuyerCookie>'
                       + '<Extrinsic name="FirstName">John</Extrinsic>'
                       + '<Extrinsic name="LastName">Smith</Extrinsic>'
                       + '<Contact role="endUser">'
                         + '<Name xml:lang="en-US">john</Name>'
                         + '<Email>smith+john@greenwingtechnology.com</Email>'
                       + '</Contact>'
                       + '<BrowserFormPost>'
                         + '<URL>https://test-sys.greenwingtech-system.com/punchout/return</URL>'
                       + '</BrowserFormPost>'
                     + '</PunchOutSetupRequest>'
                   + '</Request>'
                 </cXML>';
    xmlSTR = xmlSTR.toString().replace(/(^"|"$)/g, '');
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "xml",
        url : "https://postDataToThisURL.do",
        data : "xmlSTR",
        contentType : "text/xml",
        cache : false,
        processData : false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
            url = $(data).find("URL").text();
            console.log(data)
            console.log(url)
            window.open(url, "popupWindow", "width=1000,height=600,scrollbars=yes");              
            }
         else {
            // do something
         }
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: In the code shown, your `xmlSTR` string of XML does *not* start with a quote character, it starts with a `<` and ends with a `>`. You can't remove something that isn't there in the first place.

Comment: @nnnnnn It starts with a single quote? Is that the problem? When I change it to regular double quote `"` I start getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number` errors.

Comment: That single quote character is not part of the string, it is part of JS string literal syntax. That line creates a string containing all of the characters between the outer single quotes not including those quote characters themselves. So, e.g., `var x = 'abc'` sets `x` to a string of three characters, `abc`.

Comment: You can have a look to the following link if you really want to add quotes:
by escaping them or using combination of simple and double quotes

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quotes from this line:

```
data : "xmlSTR",
```

...to make it:

```
data : xmlSTR,
```

The way you had it, you were setting the `data` value to the literal string `"xmlSTR"`, i.e., the characters x, m, l, S, T, R. You want to set it to the *variable* `xmlSTR`.

Comment: This was it.I don't know how I could have missed that after all this time. Strings are strings no matter what language I'm using. Thank you!