# I want to change the meta tags attributes by the current url the user is in

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, meta-tags

So I have 4 different urls where I test my website. I want this meta tag in 3 enviroments :

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

but i want the 4th url to have this

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

But the problem is im working inside a .jsp file. I added an if else statement like this

```
<script type/text = "javasvript">
if (window.location.href === (url 1 || url2||url3||) ){
document.out.write("<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">");
else{
document.out.write("<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">");

</script>
```

but its actually printing the whole javascript, along with the  tags,the jsp takes my javascript as a string and never runs as code.

My questions is , should i do this in javascript or in java ? 
Should I even try to execute this if else inside the jsp page ? 
or in another file

I dont think my logic is wrong with my javascript, the biggest problem is that the whole javascript is being printed completely as a string, how do i work with jsp files and should i add java or javascript.

I feel like its a jsp java problem , do i need to use the <% %> to encapsulate my javascript or should i put java inside ?

should i make an argument like my javascript but in java style , how can i get the current url the user is in with java? please if you have questions let me know

Comment: try to change it to use single qoutes instead of double qoutes, change it to this ```'<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">'```

Comment: sir, that does not matter. its printing everything together. its even printing <script> tags as strings.

Comment: Actually it matters since using double qoutes will confuse the syntax of your js,  since it will not properly distinguish which is the starting/ending of those qoutes. Try to paste the document.out.write in the browser console and it will tell you an error

Comment: Try to read it here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript

Comment: It print it out both . This issue is more of .jsp issue and using the correct syntax to run javascript

Comment: What do you mean it printed out both? It generates "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list". Also I think it is suppose to be document.write not document.out.write

Comment: on the console , i typed both document.write("HAPPY") and document.write('happy') and both were both printed on the console

Comment: You are not getting my point. Print this in the console -> document.out.write("<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">");

Comment: And an another thing - this (meta robots) to work must be in the HTML output of the server, not generated on the browser side. Because most robots do not execute JS, just parse the HTML.

Comment: parse the html ? what do you mean ? @JozefChocholacek

Comment: The key is to realize, **where** and **when** which code is executed - JSP on the server, when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is sent to the browser), and Javascript in the browser, **after** the browser receives the **already generated** response. And robots usually ignore scripts, they only care for the HTML response.