# nested quotation marks in ajax call

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

how to do correct quotation for this

```
trHTML += '<tr><td>' + response[i].carrierName + '</td><td>' + response[i].serviceLevel + '</td><td>' + response[i].price + '</td><td>' + '<button id="buy-rate-button" onclick="getBuyingRate(' + response[i].carrierName + ',' + response[i].serviceLevel + ')" class="btn-primary btn-sm "><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></button>' + '</td></tr>';
```

Comment: You need to put escaped quotes around the strings passed into your onclick method

Comment: @Taplar Honestly looks like that isn't the case, as he is using ' to surround ". What is the issue OP? How do you want the string to look?

Comment: @Laif Single quotes are the string delimiter.  They are not literals

Comment: That isn't true at all. Both generate a string literal. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript)

Comment: `var x = 'I can use a " here because single quotes are delimiters.';`  `var x = "I can use ' here because double quotes are delimiters.";`  @Laif  `var x = 'I cause an error because this ' terminates the string too soon.';`

Comment: @Taplar Yes, that is exactly what I'm saying. That's what he did, put his code into a editor that will highlight the syntax for you, everything checks out.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6jkexLr7/  No, the OP did not. @Laif

Comment: `onclick="getBuyingRate(blah,blah2)"` <= if the values passed into the onclick method are expected to be literals, and not variable references, the strings are missing the quotes