# How to insert href URL to Javascript var?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am trying to create a script for autoreply in google apps and would love to have that reply to have some formatting. I've been getting a syntax error due to the quotes closing with the opening of the href tag. Is there a way to insert the URL into the html message? My scribbles below.

```js
function autoReply() {
var interval = 5;    //  if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
  var message = "We are out of the office until Monday morning and will reply to your email then. If you are having an emergency, please text (800) 590-2508, we'll do our best to reply as soon as possible.";
  var htmlMessage = "<p>Hi,</p><p>Thanks for your message.</p><p>We are out of the office until Monday morning and will reply to your email then. In the meantime, check out some helpful resources:</p><p><a href="https://sampleurl.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Link text</a></p><p><a href="https://anothersammple.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Link text</a></p><p>If you are having an emergency, please text (800) 000-0000, we'll do our best to get back to you as soon as possible.</p><p>Have a pleasant weekend,</p><p>My Signature</p>";
  var date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDay();
  var hour = date.getHours();
  if ([6,0].indexOf(day) > -1) {
    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      if (threads[i].isUnread()){
      threads[i].reply(message, {htmlBody: htmlMessage});
      threads[i].markRead();
      threads[i].star();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The error is on line 4

```
 var htmlMessage = "<p>Hi,</p><p>Thanks for your message.</p><p>We are out of the office until Monday morning and will reply to your email then. In the meantime, check out some helpful resources:</p><p><a href="https://sampleurl.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Link text</a></p><p><a href="https://anothersammple.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Link text</a></p><p>If you are having an emergency, please text (800) 000-0000, we'll do our best to get back to you as soon as possible.</p><p>Have a pleasant weekend,</p><p>My Signature</p>";
```

The quotes after *htmlMessage =* open the message, and the quotes after the first *href=* close it, so the rest of the message breaks the syntax.

Any insight on how to include the whole html under the **var** statement?

Thanks!

Comment: replace double quotes in the begining and end with `tild`,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use double or single quotes in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks, the answer @AkhilAravind suggested is easier to implement, but both work! Thanks, TheMaster, this is a helpful thread, I didn't know these quotes can be used interchangeably!

Answer (score 2):

add `\` before `"`

```js
 var htmlMessage = "<p>Hi,</p><p>Thanks for your message.</p><p>We are out of the office until Monday morning and will reply to your email then. In the meantime, check out some helpful resources:</p><p><a href=\"https://sampleurl.com\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\">Link text</a></p><p><a href=\"https://anothersammple.com\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\">Link text</a></p><p>If you are having an emergency, please text (800) 000-0000, we'll do our best to get back to you as soon as possible.</p><p>Have a pleasant weekend,</p><p>My Signature</p>";
```

another method is to replace `"` with `'` inside the string

Answer (score 1):

Replace `"` from the beginning and end with tild  `

Check the documentation [Here](https://blog.tildeloop.com/posts/javascript-template-literals)

```
var htmlMessage = `<p>Hi,</p><p>Thanks for your message.</p><p>We are out of the office until Monday morning and will reply to your email then. In the meantime, check out some helpful resources:</p><p><a href="https://sampleurl.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Link text</a></p><p><a href="https://anothersammple.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Link text</a></p><p>If you are having an emergency, please text (800) 000-0000, we'll do our best to get back to you as soon as possible.</p><p>Have a pleasant weekend,</p><p>My Signature</p>`;
```

```js
function autoReply() {
var interval = 5;    //  if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
  var message = "We are out of the office until Monday morning and will reply to your email then. If you are having an emergency, please text (800) 590-2508, we'll do our best to reply as soon as possible.";
  var htmlMessage = `<p>Hi,</p><p>Thanks for your message.</p><p>We are out of the office until Monday morning and will reply to your email then. In the meantime, check out some helpful resources:</p><p><a href="https://sampleurl.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Link text</a></p><p><a href="https://anothersammple.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Link text</a></p><p>If you are having an emergency, please text (800) 000-0000, we'll do our best to get back to you as soon as possible.</p><p>Have a pleasant weekend,</p><p>My Signature</p>`;
  document.write(htmlMessage)
  var date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDay();
  var hour = date.getHours();
  if ([6,0].indexOf(day) > -1) {
    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      if (threads[i].isUnread()){
      threads[i].reply(message, {htmlBody: htmlMessage});
      threads[i].markRead();
      threads[i].star();
      }
    }
  }
}
autoReply()
```

Comment: Note to op: You must [enable v8](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime) or else.

Comment: Thanks! Learning new stuff every day :)