# adding events to dynamically created elements using JS or Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am creating a div block dynamically. In the div, i am having text fields and one file field and one hyperlink. on clicking the hyperlink, the div tag will be removed from its parent. coming to the file field, i want to add onchange event to the file, which is not working for me. Please check my code and correct me if i am wrong?
this is my code:

```
<div id="incdiv" class="incdiv" name="incdiv">
<div id="increpeatdiv">
 <input type="file" class="" id="ifile" name="ifile" onchange="return filelogValidation('ifile')"/>
 </div>
  <a href='#' class="fw" onclick="repeat()">add one more Incident</a>
 </div>
 
 <script>
  function repeat(){
     var p=document.getElementById('incdiv')
      var element = document.createElement('div');
      element.id='increpeatdiv'+p.children.length;
      element.innerHTML='<input type="file" class="" id="ifile" name="ifile" onchange="return filelogValidation('ifile')"/>'+
        '<a href='#' class="fw" onclick="delete(this.parentNode.id)">Delete Incident</a>;';
        p.appendChild(element);
  }
  function delete(a){
   var p=document.getElementById(a)
  var h=document.getElementById('incdiv');
  h.removeChild(p);
  }
  function filelogValidation(input){
  var fileInput =   document.getElementById(input);        
            var filePath = fileInput.value;      
            var allowedExtensions =  
                    /(\.txt)$/i;  
                    if (!allowedExtensions.exec(filePath)) { 
                alert('Invalid file type. Please Upload .txt format'); 
                fileInput.value = ''; 
                return false; 
            }  
            else  return true;}
  }
```

I am guessing the problem to be of id "ifile". But I dont know how to solve it. Can somebody help me?

Comment: I believe this is where Event Delegation becomes useful. Instead of adding eventListeners to each element manually (which is a slower, cumbersome method), adding one event listener to the parent will allow you to add new child elements to that parent and still have the event occur on the new child.

Comment: The problem lies where you set the `innerHTML` of the `div`. You would need to escape the `'` used. Rest everything works as you intend it to. Use this: ``` element.innerHTML='<input type="file" class="" id="ifile" name="ifile" onchange="return filelogValidation(\'ifile\')"/>'+
        '<a href="#" class="fw" onclick="delete(this.parentNode.id)">Delete Incident</a>;';```

Comment: If `ifile` the name or a variable?  If it's the name: then `.. onchange="return filelogValidation(\'ifile\')"..`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use double or single quotes in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-should-i-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

```html
<div id="incdiv" class="incdiv" name="incdiv">
<div id="increpeatdiv">
 <input type="file" class="" id="ifile" name="ifile" onchange="return filelogValidation('ifile')"/>
 </div>
  <a href='#' class="fw" onclick="repeat()">add one more Incident</a>
 </div>
 
 <script>
  var i = 1; //index for doing identity to ifiles like ifile_1, ifile_2 ...
  function repeat(){
        var p=document.getElementById('incdiv')
        var element = document.createElement('div');
        element.id='increpeatdiv_'+i;
        element.innerHTML="<input type=\"file\" class=\"\" id=\"ifile_"+i+"\" name=\"ifile\" onchange=\"return filelogValidation(this.id)\"/>"+
                            "<a href='#' class=\"fw\" onclick=\"delete_(this.parentNode.id)\">Delete Incident</a>;";
        p.appendChild(element);
        i++;
    }
    function delete_(a){
        var p=document.getElementById(a)
        var h=document.getElementById('incdiv');
        h.removeChild(p);
    }
    function filelogValidation(input){
        var fileInput =   document.getElementById(input);        
        var filePath = fileInput.value;      
        var allowedExtensions =  /(\.txt)$/i;
        if (!filePath.match(allowedExtensions)) { 
            alert('Invalid file type. Please Upload .txt format'); 
            fileInput.value = ''; 
            return false; 
        }  
        else  return true;
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Bit excessive on the `"` and `\"` - that's what using `"` and `'` are for - just sometimes someone wants to put `'` inside `'` and doesn't know how