# Adding <select> tag to a <div> field using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I created a link (`<a>`) and a `<div>` field underneath. My goal is to add a `<select>` dropdown (preferably enclosed in another `<div>`) to the `<div>` field by pressing the `<a>` link. I easily managed to append simple elements using the following snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".dropdown-btn").click(function(){
    $(".canvas").append("<span>Appended text</span>");
  });
});
```

but had no luck when trying to append a more complicated element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".dropdown-btn").click(function(){
    $(".canvas").append("""<div><form>
      <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </form><div>""");
  });
});
```

My full code, in a single file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".dropdown-btn").click(function(){
          $(".canvas").append("""<div><form>
            <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
          </form><div>""");
        });
      });
    </script>

    <style>
      .canvas {
        height: 50vw;
        width: 90vw;
        background-color: powderblue;
        border:2px solid grey;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-btn">Create Dropdown</a>
    <div class="canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any error? what is the output you are getting?

Comment: This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-should-i-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this script:

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".dropdown-btn").click(function(){
          $(".canvas").append('<div><form><select name="dropdown" id="dropdown"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select></form><div>');
        });
      });
    </script>
```

its not a good option to use breaklines without use a `\`. I did all in one line its better

Comment: Not quite sure what you wanted to say "without use a `'\'`" - you can surround "code" with backtick \` to escape it

Comment: To put on multiple lines, use `'text' + 'line2' + 'line3'` with line breaks before/after the `+`