# How can i use () in html

Tags: html, angular

I use wordpress api for my angular project and in API has "" in API address like this :

```
<img src="{{importantvideo.better_featured_image.media_details.sizes.["covernews-medium"].source_url}}" class="has-border-bottom width-100pct">
```

And HTML does not recognize this and I get the error how can use API like this in my angular project

this is my property path

```
[0].better_featured_image.media_details.sizes["covernews-medium"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use single quotes as well:

```
<img src="{{importantvideo.better_featured_image.media_details.sizes.['covernews-medium'].source_url}}" class="has-border-bottom width-100pct">
```

[When should I use double or single quotes in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-should-i-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript)

Comment: Could you give some more details? At least the syntax should be valid by now. Maybe one of the properties is undefined (importantvideo, better_featured_image, sizes, ...)?