# How to pass the entire string with the " " character in it

Tags: javascript

I'm passing some query parameters to an html page. One of these is the title where in some of these there are words with " " characters.

What I notice is that when it reaches the superscript (" ") the title is truncated.

That is, if for example I have the following title:

`Chaleco López inaugurates the museum of "him"`

the title parameter will be equal to:
`Chaleco López inaugurates the museum of` (so it is incomplete because `"him"` is missing).

The code that does this is as follows:

```js
var url_string = window.location.href;
var url2 = new URL(url_string);
var titolo_url = url2.searchParams.get("title");
console.log(title_url)
```

Comment: They query parameters should be URL-escaped.

Comment: @DaveNewton What does this mean?

Comment: If I try it in firefox it works just fine

Comment: the content of the variable title is automatically taken into the code, I don't insert it myself

Comment: single quote ( ' ) is passed, while double quote (" ") is not

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try to use these brackets '' in your title

Comment: Why? That doesn't change anything in this case, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/242833/17852419). Btw they aren't called *brackets* but *quotes*