# jquery appended div onclick not work first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, onclick

this is my code

html :

```
<input type="text" class="js-input">  
<div class="js-autofill"></div>
```

jquery :

```
var myarray = ['apple' , 'orange'];
myarray.forEach(element => {
$('.js-autofill').append(
`<div class="js-item" data-value="`+element+`">` +element+ `</div>`
)
})

$(document).on('click','.js-item',function(){
$('.js-input').val($(this).attr('data-value'))
})
```

problem is `.js-item` onclick not working at firsttime - it's work when i doubleclick
i can't find why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `.val()` to `.text()` for the div click.

From [Docs](https://api.jquery.com/val/)

> The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea. When called on an empty collection, it returns undefined.

```
$('.js-input').val($(this).text())
```

2 -  Your div string in append has mismatch quotes, the correct order should be as below.

```
`<div class='js-item' data-value='` + element + `'>` + element + `</div>`
```

Also its helpful for you to read: [When should I use double or single quotes in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-should-i-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript)

---

Working code below

```js
var myarray = ['apple', 'orange'];
myarray.forEach(element => {
  $('.js-autofill').append(
    `<div class='js-item' data-value='` + element + `'>` + element + `</div>`
  )
})

$(document).on('click', '.js-item', function() {
  $('.js-input').val($(this).text())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="js-input">
<div class="js-autofill"></div>
```

Comment: Also class="js-item data-value='` + element + `'" is not correct. It creates class="js-item data-value='apple'"