# Javascript: read alert message from file and display with line break

Tags: javascript, newline, alert

How can I in Javascript read strings from a textfile and display them in an alert box with newlines?

Suppose I have an ASCII textfile "messages.txt" containing two lines:

```
AAA\nBBB\nCCC
DDD\nEEE\nFFF
```

In javascript, I read the file content and store it in a variable "m":

```
    var m;
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
      { if ((xmlhttp.readyState==4) && (xmlhttp.status==200 || xmlhttp.status==0))
        { m = xmlhttp.responseText.split('\n'); };
      };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "messages.txt", false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Now when I display the first message with

```
console.log(m[0]);
alert(m[0]);
```

it is shown exactly as in the textfile and with no line breaks; i.e

```
AAA\nBBB\nCCC
```

and not as

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

Changing  **\n**  to  **\\n**, **\r\n**, **\\r\\n** or **%0D%0A** in the textfile doesn't help; the alert is still displayed as one line including the escape characters without replacing them by newline. Changing the encoding of "messages.txt" from ASCII to UTF-8 didn't help either.

**To clarify the problem:**
When m is read from the file "message.txt", it is split into an array of strings. m[0] equal to "AAA\nBBB\nCCC".

```
console.log(m[0]);                  // displays AAA\nBBB\nCCC
console.log('AAA\nBBB\nCCC');       // displays AAA
                                    //          BBB
                                    //          CCC

console.log(typeof(m[0])            // displays string
console.log(m[0]=="AAA\nBBB\nCCC"); // displays false
```

Why is m[0] not equal to "AAA\nBBB\nCCC" (even if exactly this is what is displayed in the console)? I guess, that is the reason why no line breaks appear.

Comment: Change `split('\n')` from single quotes to `split("\n")` to double quotes and see what happens. Single quotes will not intetpret escaped chars where `\n` is escaped. So you get all slashes as escaped as well as other logical errors, unless you split by `"\n"`.

Comment: @mardubbles This did the trick - thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah im not on here for rep so you can accept that as an answer. Glad it worked out for you.

Comment: @mardubbles Unfortunately, I was wrong and replacing single with double quotes didn't solve the problem (it changed how the text file is split into an array of string; the array elements still show with an \n and no line breaks)
This aside, I am new to stackoverflow and don't know how to accept a comment as an answer.

Comment: You can't. Comments are not meant to be answers.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add  another `\` at `split('\n')` to be `split('\\n')`

or change the single quote to douple quotes `split("\n")`

also i encourage you to read this quick article about ['Single' vs "Double" quotes](https://flexiple.com/double-vs-single-quotes-javascript/)

Comment: Splitting the string is not the problem; that works fine. I clarified the problem in my initial post: The variable "m[0]" which is equal to "A\nB\nC" does not result in a line break in an alert, whereas `var M = "A\nB\C"; alert(M);` results in linebreaks.

Comment: I know , please run it as mentioned and you will see that now it sperated

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes don't interpret newline breaks (`\n`). So, you need to change the quotes in your `split()` method to have double quotes.

Use the `split()` function like so.

```js
const str = "Hi! I'm text!\nIsn't this supposed to be newline?";

console.log(str.split("\n"));
```

This should return an array like so when run.

```js
[
  "Hi! I'm text!",
  "Isn't this supposed to be newline?"
]
```

This is how to separate your text with line breaks.

---

For more information, see this other [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-should-i-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript) question.

Comment: Splitting the string is not the problem; that works fine. I clarified the problem in my initial post: The variable "m[0]" which is equal to "A\nB\nC" does not result in a line break in an alert, whereas var M = "A\nB\C"; alert(M); results in linebreaks.