# <script> tag not loading

Tags: javascript, php

The jquery script of my program loads when there are no other elements on the file, but doesn't work when there are other code added on the page. JQuery library is loaded.

The following works ok:

```
<body text="#676767" link="#0000ff" vlink="#800080" alink="#ff0000">

<div id="loadmkts"></div>

<script>
var $scores = $("#loadmkts");
    
setInterval(function () {
    $scores.load("/markets1.php?eventid=31680557&inplay=yes);
}, 5000);
</script>
 

</body>
```

The following doesn't work when other code is added to the page, e.g. the php code to use variables as the url parameters.

```
<body text="#676767" link="#0000ff" vlink="#800080" alink="#ff0000">

    <?php
    $eventid="31680557";
    $inplay="yes";
    $acct="100000";
    ?>
    <div id="loadmkts"></div>
   
    <script>
    var $scores = $("#loadmkts");
    var evid=<?php echo $eventid; ?>;
    var inplay=<?php echo $inplay; ?>;
    setInterval(function () {
        $scores.load("/markets1.php?eventid="+evid+"&inplay="+inplay);
    }, 5000);
    </script>
         
    </body>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried to check what the final script looks like in the dev tools?

Comment: my guess is your script will be evaluated faster than php code. Not sure if it's really the case. But you can try to use AJAX right?

Comment: @Sempoinus ...... kindly explain the AJAX option please. thanks.

Comment: What's the point of having PHP generate JS variables, and then doing string concatenation with those in JS - why not directly put these values into the URL with your PHP code already?

Answer (score 1):

You have to enclose the PHP variables in quotes - declaring string in JS. Otherwise the $inplay will print as a variable "yes" (which is undefined at this point) in the JS code.

```
<?php
$eventid="31680557";
$inplay="yes";
$acct="100000";
?>
<div id="loadmkts"></div>

<script>
var $scores = $("#loadmkts");
var evid='<?php echo $eventid; ?>';
var inplay='<?php echo $inplay; ?>';
setInterval(function () {
    $scores.load("/markets1.php?eventid="+evid+"&inplay="+inplay);
}, 5000);
</script>
     
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. Using php varibales in the js script requires double quotation marks. Single quotes didn't work. All ok now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-should-i-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript?rq=1